# Python access variable in while loop

Tags: python

I have this simple Python 3 script

```
def myfunction(current):
    current += 1
    myvalue = 'Test Value'
    print(current)
    return current

current = 1
while ( current < 10 ):
    current = myfunction(current)
```

It works great but I am trying to use the myvalue variable in the while loop.  How can I get access to the variable?

Comment: How can you  ? The scope is different ;)

Comment: You only return one value from `myfunction`, the others are inaccessible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to return `myvalue` if you want to use it.

```
def myfunction(current):
    current += 1
    myvalue = 'Test Value'
    print(current)
    return current, myvalue

current = 1
while ( current < 10 ):
    current, myvalue = myfunction(current)
    print(myvalue)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can return multiple variables from a function

Try with the below code:

```
def myfunction(current):
    current += 1
    myvalue = 'Test Value'
    print(current)
    return current, myvalue

current = 1
while ( current < 10 ):
    current, myvalue = myfunction(current)
```

Comment: Nitpicking: In fact you only return one value from the function. This value is a `tuple` with two elements which is unpacked to two variables in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 3):

`myvalue` variable is local to the method `myfunction`. You can't access it outside that method.

You may either

- use a global variable, or
- return value from `myfunction`

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 ways:

1: make the variable global:

```
myvalue = 'initvalue'

def myfunction(current):
    global myvalue 
    current += 1
    myvalue = 'Test Value'
    print(current)
    return current

current = 1
while ( current < 10 ):
    current = myfunction(current)
```

2: return multiple variables from your function function

```
def myfunction(current):
    current += 1
    myvalue = 'Test Value'
    print(current)
    return current, myvalue

current = 1
while ( current < 10 ):
    current, myvalue = myfunction(current)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you wanted all the values inside the function with the same identities, you could also try this (but do ensure you are not using the same variable names outside, which kinda destroys the purpose)

```
def myfunction(current):
    current += 1
    myvalue = 'Test Value'
    return locals()
```

which should give you a dictionary of the variables. The output for `print myfunction(1)` will be

```
{'current': 2, 'myvalue': 'Test Value'}
```